# What is the fastest way of parsing ~1Gb binary files in python while searching for a specific 'substring'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, binaryfiles

So, I've got several hundreds of ~1-5Gb binary files.
The insides look like this:

```
b'*<unixtime> <several parameters of varying length> N<number> [<huge raw hex data>]\n'
b'which can sometimes span\n'
b'several lines\n'
b'*<unixtime> <several parameters of varying length> N<number> [<huge raw hex data>]\n'
```

All the specified parameters are binary by nature, and the hex payload is basically a TLV-encoded sequence.
My goal is to find a specific N, then take a look at payload bytes for a specific byte that sets the type of the payload. If it's what Im searching for, then my decoding algorithm should cut this payload and decode it.

My main cause of concern is that parsing these files takes a frustrating amount of time, tens of minutes. I was wondering if there is a more efficient solution.

My code is very basic:

```
filtered = []
with open('/Users/tele/buffer.lg', 'rb') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        payload = []
        if b'N00324' in line:
            current_part = line.split(b'[')[1].strip(b']\n')
            if not current_part[2] == 0xcc: continue  
            payload.append(current_part)
            next_part = next(reader)
            while not next_part.startswith(b'*'):
                payload.append(next_part.rstrip(b'\n'))
                next_part = next(reader)
            filtered.append(b''.join(payload))
```

What bugs me is its speed, certainly, but also the fact that I might lose data if I happen to have a second payload with the same N00324 element after I force iterator to get the next line. It won't be processed altogether, which is kinda not intended, but the workaround is still not clear.
I've tried to play with `numpy.frombuffer`, but to no avail — just a simple `pass` statement takes longer than the aforementioned code. Apparently, converting to ndarray is pretty expensive.
So, is there a way to speed up the process?

Comment: Is it really binary data, or is it hex ASCII hex digits, like in an XML CDATA?  So, is it the string "ABC" or is it the string "646566"?  It's problematic to do line-by-line things on a file with binary data, since you might have 0x0A characters in there.

Comment: @TimRoberts it's not plain ASCII since the payload can get  bytes all the way up to 0xFF. It's sort of a dirty mixture between strings and bytes, which I've got no control over.

Comment: You might consider skipping the line-by-line stuff, and read the file in chunks of, say, 100MB.  You can then scan for your N strings in bulk.  You'll need to check of the chunk ends with a partial match; you can do that by just taking the last 10 bytes of chunk N and adding that to the beginning of chunk N+1.

Comment: The part about the loss of data and the second payload is unclear to me. Did you mean that the "N00324" string can be in the raw hex data located on a new line? Can you add an example to clarify this point? (if possible with quite-realistic values)

Comment: I thought lines are part of text files, not binary ones.

Comment: one thing that can definitely speed up your read times is to read bigger chucks into memory at once, and not line by line,  especially if you are using a hard drive, as it only spins up to 5K rpm, so that's only 5000 lines per second, if you cannot skip any line and the memory is big enough to fit the entire file then reading it all into memory with a single read is not a bad idea.

Comment: @AhmedAEK CPython (as well as PyPy and certainly all mainstream implementation of Python) does not use raw buffered read. It ise internally the libc which has its own buffer (all read/writes are buffered except huge ones). The size of the libc buffer is optimized for high-performance sequential read. This means that many small read are still quite fast in C. However, you are right, this should be faster because of the overhead of CPython calls and the line parsing.

Comment: Have you considered memory-mapping your files in order to search? https://pymotw.com/3/mmap/index.html

Comment: I think the best thing to do is to run cProfile on your script to see where the bottleneck is, if it's all from reading from disk (and it probably is) then there's nothing you can do about it, but if the bottleneck is from python then there's definitely a lot you can do.

Comment: I'm guessing your files are actually 1 gigabyte (GB) rather than the gigabit (Gb) you have written? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks a lot! Your suggestion increased my speed 20-fold! It's a miracle!

Comment: I love it when a plan works!!! Good luck with your project!